# Como remover o valor da variável com JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Estou testando para limpar uma lista de objetos que é passada para o JSP, e executo o comando abaixo:

```jsp
<c:remove var="lista" scope="session" />
<c:out value="${lista}"></c:out>
```

Porém quando chamo a página com o JSP, encontro o endereço de memória da lista que deveria ter sido excluída e preenche normalmente os elementos HTML com os atributos dos objetos que estão definidos na lista.

**EDIT**

Estou utilizando uma tag criada por mim, isso pode influenciar? (objeto contém lista):

```
<ec:form beanName="objeto" controllerUrl="/parametro1/parametro2">
```

Sendo que se eu passar removendo o objeto com:

```
<c:remove var="objeto">
```

Estoura um `NullPointerException`.